# How to get the text that is appended to the div using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am appending the text to the div like

```
span.insertBefore("#text");
```

here span represents the text that is appending. How can i get the text on any other event like button click etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get the text by using javascript like:

`var text = document.getElementById('#text').innerHtml();`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function of jquery element using **[selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

```
txt = $("#text").text();             //id selector
txt = $('.classOfElement').text()   //class selector
```